# Latest Modification Time Stamp for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date Modified Time Stamp of an Excel Sheet Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630792/date-modified-time-stamp-of-an-excel-sheet-using-vba)

Hi I've an excel workbook...I want to jot down the time stamp in cell A2 of sheet 1 for the latest modification made in any row or column of sheet2 of the workbook.

So my problem is two fold:
1. Want to trace the latest modification time.
2. Want to make the cell A2 of sheet1 as user protected so that no one can tamper with the traced time stamp.
Here is the code on which i was workung...and its not correct as its not doing anything..if it would have bben doing anything then definitely there was not any problem for me in sharing it but as its not doing anything so its a bit useless.

```
       Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Dim Row, Col

       For Row = 2 To Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       For Col = 1 To Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
       If Target.Cells(Row, Col) Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Sheet1.Cells("A2") = now()
       Application.EnableEvents = True
       End If
       Next Col
       Next Row

       End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us some code.

Comment: @DougGlancy: I don't know at all how to solve the second part of my problem.

Comment: There also i dint get any answer..

Comment: You did get a good suggestion in the comments about the first part of your question. You should read the faq about what's expected in questions. You need to show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

To get you headed in the right direction:

- Right Click on the sheet tab for sheet 2.
- Select "View Code".
- You'll see two drop-downs at the top of the module. In the first one select "Worksheet". In the second one select "Change".
- This will create the template for the Worksheet_Change procedure, which will fire whenever the user changes a value in Sheet2.
- Use that to write the time stamp into cell A2 of sheet1.

For the second part of your problem, protect sheet 1. In code, that's:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

And before you write to cell A2, unprotect it first:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect
```

Look up the Protect and Unprotect methods in help if you want to add a password.

(Bear in mind that sheet protection is pretty weak, even with a password. For casual work it's OK, but it CAN be cracked by users if they're determined to do it. A better approach might be to write the value into a sheet which has a visible property of xlVeryHidden so that most users won't even know it's there (if you apply protection to the VBA project). Again, not uncrackable but better than having it in a visible sheet.)